# Spark: memory issues (GC overhead limit exceeded) when using cogroup with ListBuffer in Scala

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, scala-2.10, listbuffer

I have the following code:

```
 fTuple2.cogroup(gTuple2).flatMap { t =>

      val fList: ListBuffer[classF] = ListBuffer()
      val gList: ListBuffer[classG] = ListBuffer()

      while (t._2._2.iterator.hasNext) {
        gList.add(t._2._2.iterator.next)
      }

      val fIter = t._2._1.iterator
      while (fIter.hasNext) {
        val f = fIter.next
        val hn = f.getNum()

        //-----------------
        try {
          val gValue = FindGUtiltity.findBestG(hn, gList)
          f.setG(gValue)
        } catch {
          case e: Exception => println("exception caught: " + e);
        }
        fList.add(f)
      }
      fList
 }
```

and at line:

```
gList.add(t._2._2.iterator.next)
```

I got the following error:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ListBuffer.scala:176)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ListBuffer.scala:45)
    at scala.collection.mutable.BufferLike$class.appendAll(BufferLike.scala:147)
    at scala.collection.mutable.AbstractBuffer.appendAll(Buffer.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.mutable.BufferLike$class.append(BufferLike.scala:142)
    at scala.collection.mutable.AbstractBuffer.append(Buffer.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$MutableBufferWrapper.add(Wrappers.scala:80)
```

When the gList size is 1, it worked fine. But if the average gList size is ~ 5, the memory issues occurs. The total number of instances of classG is not too big, so the total gList shouldn't be too large. Is gList actually duplicating itself in Scala? Is there a better way to create List in Scala? or should I use some Java List here instead?

Thank you!

Comment: I resolved the memory issue by assigning the iterator to a value first:    val gIter=t._2._2.iterator   while (gIter.hasNext) {
        gList.add(gIter.next)
      }       Though I am not sure why this solved the problem, it seems to work. ... does anyone have any idea? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your while loop will never end as long as there's at least one element to iterate over, because you are requesting a new iterator with every cycle and getting the first element every time, adding it to a list that blows the memory.

That's why (based on your comment) getting an iterator only once and assigning it to a val solved it.

Comment: so each t._2._2.iterator is actually creating a new iterator?

Comment: @Edamame yes, that's exactly how it behaves